# creating custom shape / drawable - 6 sided button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-shape

Is it possible to create a completely custom shape in xml? I'm trying to create a button which looks like this: http://s11.postimg.org/e4izrlgrj/image.png (a mockup i did in photoshop)

I need to be able to create the outline shape and the small blue tab top right.

I have tried with some xml but getting nowhere close. I'm aware you can do something with Path class but never used it, is this the only option?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about a completely custom shape but have you tryed using font icons?

Take a look at this: http://css-tricks.com/svg-sprites-use-better-icon-fonts/

Comment: I will take a look at this as an option. Thank you